# How add space in between box

Tags: html, css

Hi i'm create website for mobile phone,
but i have a problem

i want add space in between box css

this is **screenshot**

[image]

and this is **my code**

```
<?php 
include "connection.php";
?>
<ul  data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-divider-theme="a">
              <li data-role="list-divider"><center><font color="white"><b>Sekolah Rekomendasi</b></font></center></li>      
            <div id="owl-demo-5">
            <?php
            $dataskl = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT alamat,diskon,link,logo,kode,nama_sekolah,vvip from sekolah where vvip='Ya' order by id_sekolah desc limit 0,10");
            while ($skl = mysqli_fetch_object($dataskl))
            { 
            $jd = $skl->link;
            ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <div style="border-style:solid;border-width:2px;width:162px;"   class='product_item'>
                <div>
                <a data-ajax="false" href='<?php echo $jd ?>'>
                    <img style="float:left; margin-right:8px;width:70px;height:85px;"   src='images/sekolah/logo/<?php echo $skl->logo ?>' class='c_image_1' alt=''>
                </a>
                <?php if ($skl->diskon=="Ya") { ?>
                <div class='ribbon'><img src='images/biaya.png' alt=''></div>
                <?php } else { } ?>
                </div>
                <?php 
                $ptng_nama =  substr($skl->nama_sekolah,0,15);
                $ptng_alamat =  substr($skl->alamat,0,34);
                ?>
                    <div  class='product_info'>
                        <a style="text-decoration:none" data-ajax="false" href='<?php echo $jd ?>'><font size="1"><?php echo $ptng_nama ?></font></a><br/>
                        <font size="1"><?php echo $ptng_alamat ?></font><br/>
                        <?php 
                        $datac_pre = mysql_query("select count(id_kunjungan) as hitung from sekolah_kunjungan where kode='$skl->kode' and tgl_kunjungan between '$web->range_awal' and '$web->range_akhir'");
                        $cpre = mysql_fetch_object($datac_pre); ?>
                        <font size='1' color='blue'>Dilihat : <?php echo $cpre->hitung ?></font>
                    </div>
                </div>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <?php  } ?>               

            </div>
        </ul>
```

How to add space in between box ?
helpme thank's

Comment: Have you tried putting "style=padding-left:10px;" inside your div tag..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin` or `padding` property in the css rules for those blocks.

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:300px;
}
.a {
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="a"></div><div class="b"></div>
```

Comment: As he has applied a border to those divs, padding seems inappropriate so margin would be the best approach.

Comment: @Propolys Since the css was not shared. Not sure about the element on which the border was used. If it was on the right element, then padding on left element will  work too.

Comment: i try in my code, doesn't work.
see my code update  > http://pastebin.com/4RKrZueu

Comment: @MuhamadRidwansyah create a fiddle to demonstrate your issue